# Extract unique json keys from a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the below column which is in json format. I need to get the unique json keys from all the rows in the 
below dataframe. Not sure whether pandas has any inbuilt functions to do this.

```
 Col3

 {"a": 2000, "b": 1}
 {'c': 'Go bug go','d': 'go_line21','e': 'movie','duration': 2166}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question would be better with actual code. The column as given isn't in json format, since it has both double-quoted (correct) and single-quoted (not json format) elements.

It's also not clear whether the columns are being stored as dicts or as strings.

That said, drawing from [this answer on converting from string to dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169718/convert-string-to-dict-then-access-keyvalues-how-to-access-data-in-a-class) and [this answer on splitting a dictionary into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231591/splitting-dictionary-list-inside-a-pandas-column-into-separate-columns), here's how to get the answer if the columns are in fact in json format : use json.loads and [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) then grab the column names.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col3' : 
               ['{"a": 2000, "b": 1}',
                '{"c": "Go bug go", "d": "go_line21", "e": "movie", "duration": 2166}']})

json_normalize(df['Col3'].apply(json.loads)).columns.to_list()
```

If you have to correct incorrect quoting, then you need to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169718/convert-string-to-dict-then-access-keyvalues-how-to-access-data-in-a-class).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dataframe from it and grab the keys as a list:

```
list(pd.DataFrame(df['Col3'].to_list()).columns)
```

output:

```
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'duration']
```